# Windows 10 Phone - UWP app webview html page does not scale to full screen

Tags: webview, uwp

I have a simple html page loaded to the webview control in Windows Phone  which does not scale to the full screen and a white patch appears (as the image attached).

[image]
The WebView code is as follows:

```
<Page
x:Class="loadtime.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:loadtime"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView x:Name="mainWebView"></WebView>
</Grid>
```

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:red; border: 1px solid blue;">
    </body>
</html>
```

Whats could be the reason? Is there any other properties that need to be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Set WebView `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch`

Below is my full code.

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App16.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App16"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Loaded="Page_Loaded"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView x:Name="mainWebView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App16
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string Loaded = "<html lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /><title></title></head><body style=\"background-color:red; border: 1px solid blue;\"></body></html>";
            mainWebView.NavigateToString(Loaded);
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is the output.**

[image]

Comment: This does not help, it still does not scale to full screen:                        <WebView x:Name="mainWebView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></WebView>

Comment: @Neena That is real strange. I just created a blank project and used your html example and your page example and it rendered perfectly fine. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have done the same but it does not scale. Is this something to do with the device type? I am using Lumia 650, Version 1607. OS build 10.0.14393.448. Screen Resolution 720X1280

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the status bar, this resolved the issue.

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
        {
            await StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem. But, just adding Margin resolved my issues and opened in full screen, here is my code which might help you,

```
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" Height="auto" Margin="0,0,0,0"
```

Just set margin 0 and all good to go, Hope that help you, :)

Full view in UWP Web view example:

[image: UWP Web View]